# Не может найти элемент Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="top-menu-social"]/div/ul/li[5]').click() ### ютуб

    driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/center/a/i').click()
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('login')

    element = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="identifierNext"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    
    #driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="identifierNext"]').click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('password')
    element = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="passwordNext"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

    #driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lCoei YZVTmd SmR8')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если except: появился, ожидайте элемент и производите еще раз нажатие.

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="view_container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
except:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="view_container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как через пробел в `class=` идет перечисление разных классов, нужно при поиске через `By.CLASS_NAME` и через `By.CSS_SELECTOR` заменить пробел на точку.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lCoei.YZVTmd.SmR8')
```

Comment: Не в этом проблема. Я уже все варианты перепробовал. Не может найти элемент и все

Comment: @team arden Да если это не срабатывает, то может быть несколько других "подводных камней" - элемент может находиться на iframe, быть скрытым в css, находиться внутри тегов script и т.д.. Для точного определения нужна ссылка на сайт.

Comment: Вообщем я понял где рыть, для меня это просто практика!